# Async Tests - Mocha and Chai - Ensure the done() callback is being called

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying test my container component methods. My container had a async method that load all proposals and set in the state. Example.:

```
loadProposal(proposalId) {
    return axios
            .get("http://localhost:9292/api/proposal_drafts/1.json")
            .then(response => {
              this.setState({
                proposal: Immutable.fromJS(response.data)
              })
            })
  }
```

So, to test this method i get the component instance and call the method (the api url is mocked).

```
it("sets proposal in the state", (done) => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Container/>)

    loadProposalRequest(1)

    wrapper.instance().loadProposal(1).then(() => {
      chai.expect(wrapper.state().proposal).to.be(Map)
      done()
    })
  })
```

But i get this error from console:

> Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being
>   called in this test.

Ops: If i put a console.log(wrapper.state()) inside then() . The log shows my state correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `chai.expect()` throws an error (which I think is what's happening), two things will happen:

- `done` won't get called, because of the thrown error;
- the error won't get caught, because there's not additional error handling.

You should use Mocha's promise support instead to remove both issues:

```
it("sets proposal in the state", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Container/>)

  loadProposalRequest(1)

  return wrapper.instance().loadProposal(1).then(() => {
    chai.expect(wrapper.state().proposal).to.be(Map)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised)

you can write code that expresses what you really mean:

```
return doSomethingAsync().should.eventually.equal("foo");
```

or if you have a case where `return` is not preferable (e.g. style considerations) or not possible (e.g. the testing framework doesn't allow returning promises to signal asynchronous test completion), then you can use the following workaround (where `done()` is supplied by the test framework):

```
doSomethingAsync().should.eventually.equal("foo").notify(done);
```